# Use Array.Sort to only sort elements and not index numbers?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, unity-game-engine, indexof

First a quick run-down of my code..

here I have two Arrays, a GameObject, and a float Array..

```
public class PlaceManager : MonoBehaviour
{
private GameObject[] playerList;
private float[] distanceValue;
```

On start I call the FindAllPlayers Function and on Update I call two Functions.

```
void Start()
{
    FindAllPlayers();
}
void Update()
{
    FindPlayerXValues();
    DeterminePlace();
}
```

The function of FindAllPlayers is to find all objects with the tag "Player" and assign the index number to the player (Later it will be ordered by the players slot for multiplayer like if they are player1, player2, etc.).

```
public void FindAllPlayers()
{
    if (playerList == null)
    {
        playerList = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
        for (int i = 0; i < playerList.Length; i++)
        {
            playerList[i].GetComponent<CharacterStats>().playerNumber = i;
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of FindPlayerXValues is to populate the distanceValue array with the X position of all the players and assigning them in order by the order they were populated in the playerList array. (This also makes it so playerList[1] == distanceValue[1]!)

```
public void FindPlayerXValues()
{
    if (playerList != null)
    {
        distanceValue = new float[] { playerList[0].transform.position.x * -1,
        playerList[1].transform.position.x * -1,
        playerList[2].transform.position.x * -1,
        playerList[3].transform.position.x * -1,
        playerList[4].transform.position.x * -1};
    }
}
```

And  the DeterminePlace function first Sorts the distanceValue Array. Next  it updates the position.

What my plan is that it grabs the myPosition Variable from the linked playerList array element and then assigns the index number of where the linked distanceValue element is after the sort.

```
    public void DeterminePlace()
    {
        Array.Sort(distanceValue);
        for (int i = 0; i < distanceValue.Length; i++)
        {

            playerList[i].GetComponent<CharacterStats>().myPosition = Array.IndexOf(distanceValue, distanceValue[i]); 
        }
    }
}
```

As of right now the players myPosition variable stays the same no matter where the distanceValue element is located. This was how I expected this to work.

```
[0]=distanceValue[0] = 1st Place --> [0]=distanceValue[3] = 1st Place
[1]=distanceValue[1] = 2nd Place --> [1]=distanceValue[0] = 2nd Place
[2]=distanceValue[2] = 3rd Place --> [2]=distanceValue[1] = 3rd Place
[3]=distanceValue[3] = 4th Place --> [3]=distanceValue[2] = 4th Place
[4]=distanceValue[4] = 5th Place --> [4]=distanceValue[4] = 5th Place
```

This is what seems to be the reality...

```
[0]=distanceValue[0] = 1st Place --> [3]=distanceValue[3] = 4th Place
[1]=distanceValue[1] = 2nd Place --> [0]=distanceValue[0] = 1st Place
[2]=distanceValue[2] = 3rd Place --> [1]=distanceValue[1] = 2nd Place
[3]=distanceValue[3] = 4th Place --> [2]=distanceValue[2] = 3rd Place
[4]=distanceValue[4] = 5th Place --> [4]=distanceValue[4] = 5th Place
```

What can I implement into my code to get something closer to the first result?

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you start off so that distanceValue[n] corresponds to playerList[n], but then you sort distanceValue, which breaks the pairing?

Comment: Do you perhaps need to use [the overload of `Array.Sort()` that takes two arrays as parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Array_)? This will sort using values from the first array, and will sort the second array in the same way as it sorts the first array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is this line:

```
playerList[i].GetComponent<CharacterStats>().myPosition = Array.IndexOf(distanceValue, distanceValue[i]);
```

This is looking through the `distanceValue` array for the index of the value at index `i` of that same array.... i.e., that is always just going to return i.

Perhaps you meant:

```
playerList[i].GetComponent<CharacterStats>().myPosition = Array.IndexOf(distanceValue, playerList[i].transform.position.x * -1);
```

which should, for each player, find their X position in the sorted distance array, and thus their ranking.

Comment: By Golly I think you got it! All I need to do is reverse the Sort, It says the player in first is 4th. Thank you very much!